# Angular: Dynamic value to breadcrumbs not working

Tags: angular

I want to set breadcrumbs with the text from db but it seems routes a registered before that. How can i achieve that.

Below is the code from app.routing module:

Static:

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: {breadcrumb:'Home'},
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
},
```

Dynamic:

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: {breadcrumb:DefaultValueSingletonClass.Instance[0]},   
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
},
```